# Understanding Backone js routing with query parameters

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This may seem trivial to some but i have an application that performs a search and updates the  browser history with the hash including the search term.

```
routes: {
"": "search",
"search/:query": "searchSetup"
},
```

from what i understand about hashtags, valid hashtags should not contain spaces. How does everyone handle this where a user searches for e.g. **video games**. 
it seems that when i search for the term above the navigate event is fired twice
My regex is currently abysmal.

```
    RT.App.searchRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        RT.App.vent.on("change:hash", function(searchTerm) {
            console.log("chnaging hash")
            this.navigate('search/'+searchTerm);
        }, this);
    },
    routes: {
        "": "search",
        "search/:query": "searchSetup"
    },
    createView: function () {
        //has view already been instatiated?
        if(!$("#forms-demo").length) {
            new RT.App.views.AdvancedSearchView({
                el: '#ui-search',
                model: new RT.App.models.AdvancedSearch()
            });

        }   

    },
    search: function() {
        //clear any previous search if any
        this.createView();
    },
    searchSetup: function(query) {
        this.createView();
        var $searchinputEl = $("#search-term"),     

        //check if storage entry exists and if it matches the query entered
            storedSearchTerm = amplify.store('search');
        if((!_.isUndefined(storedSearchTerm) && !_.isUndefined(query)) && (storedSearchTerm.term === unescape(query))) {

            //retrieve storage and perform search based on preferences
            RT.App.searchCategoryOptions.attributes = storedSearchTerm.sections;

            //each filter view options should now set the correct options
            RT.App.vent.trigger("change:options");

            //add search query to search input
            $searchinputEl.val(storedSearchTerm.term);

            //trigger search

            $(".trigger-search").trigger("click");
        }
    }
});
$(function(){

    // Instantiate the router
    var searchRouter = new RT.App.searchRouter();
    if(Backbone.History.started) {
        Backbone.history.stop();
    }
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle spaces.  Just make sure to encode your search terms first.

```
this.navigate('search/'+ encodeURIComponent(searchTerm));
```